# How does binary parse with php

Tags: php, apache, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

**1.**
Because all the data are stored in a computer in a binary format, consider the following instruction:

```
$string = "welcome to $name";
```

If we save php file in utf-8 encoding format, the instruction would be saved in the following form:

```
00100100 01110011 01110100 01110010 01101001 01101110 01100111 00100000 00111101 00100000 00100010 01110111 01100101 01101100 01100011 01101111 01101101 01100101 00100000 01110100 01101111 00100000 00100100 01101110 01100001 01101101 01100101 00100010 00111011
```

When I open this file in an editor, I see the letters and signs etc. correctly but how does the php interpreter see the content?

Does it see the content in this form?

```
00100100 01110011 01110100 01110010 01101001 01101110 01100111 00100000 00111101 00100000 00100010 01110111 01100101 01101100 01100011 01101111 01101101 01100101 00100000 01110100 01101111 00100000 00100100 01101110 01100001 01101101 01100101 00100010 00111011
```

Or, does it see instructions in this form?

```
$string = "01110111 01100101 01101100 01100011 01101111 01101101 01100101 00100000 01110100 01101111 00100000 00100100 01101110 01100001 01101101 01100101";
```

or:

```
$string = "01110111 01100101 01101100 01100011 01101111 01101101 01100101 00100000 01110100 01101111 00100000 $name";
```

or:

```
$string = "welcome to $name";
```

I do not exactly know how php sees the content of a program and what is does with the data.
If it does not see the content in a binary form, so when the string or integer and other data are converted to binary format?

**2.**
In php files, the header of php file is set on utf-8 by default. Also, we can set the encoding process in html files by making use of charset meta-tag. Encoding method can also be changed on the browser. 

Now, the question is that whether the content sent by the server as a response to a browser is in a binary format or not? If the answer is negative, what is the use of encoding?

Comment: "Seeing" is a bit of a weird way of putting it. The computer exclusively works with binary data. It doesn't "see" human readable letters at all, at any point.

Comment: so is php interpreter parsed instructions as binary?

Comment: PHP only makes a basic distinction: ASCII-compatible single-byte encoding or UTF-16 determined by BOM. It's the only thing it needs to be able to find and parse code.

Comment: You might want to read this: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Comment: he said: "A parser would read this as follows `$string = "11100110 10111100 10100010 11100101 10101101 10010111";`" why would not  `$string` parse to binary?

Comment: Well, it does, that analogy is a bit strenuous anyway and tries to illustrate a different point. The more pertinent quote is: *"The PHP parser is looking for certain characters that tell it what to do. `$` (`00100100`) signals the start of a variable, `=` (`00111101`) an assignment, `"` (`00100010`) the start and end of a string and so on. Anything else that doesn't have any special significance to the parser is just taken as a literal byte sequence."*